# How to 'unuse' Agg in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I added

```py
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

to one of my Python scripts in order to try plotting using a cluster.
Now I can't plot anything, even when trying on my own MacBook. The error message states:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

Can I also 'unuse' agg in Matplotlib?

Comment: Agg won’t let you render to a gui.  If you want to do that “use” another backend.  If you are on a cluster, or otherwise using agg, then you will need to save the file using fig.savefig.

Answer (score 0):

Gave me a bit of a headache too as I refused to reload the kernel for my entire notebook just to get this back to default. Thus,

Start a new kernel that you use for your scripts and enter:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
default_backend = mpl.get_backend()
print(default_backend)  # Output is specific to your IDE's kernel
```

Which now output the default GUI for your IDE/Kernel:

```
'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

Subsequently in your script simply use it to reset to your default GUI.

```
mpl.use(default_backend)
```

Note that this is not in the documentation of "valid" strings of mpl.use(str), as it is a module externally loaded by your IDE.